# What retrospective analysis happens after a clinical trial fails?

Tags: human-biology, pharmacology, philosophy-of-science

After a failed pharmaceutical clinical trial, what retrospective analyses are typically performed to understand why the drug program failed the trial? For example, are further experiments done to determine whether it was due to inaccurately predicted pharmacokinetics versus whether the biological target was non-causal? Do such analyses look only at the data gathered in the clinical trial itself, or are there teams which do further experiments to understand the precise mechanism of the failure? Are there investigations to replicate and reproduce earlier data and reports that led to the green light for the clinical trial, in order to catch fraudulent data generated by company scientists?

Another way of asking this question: how do pharmaceutical and biotech companies internally implement the scientific method, given that they don't publish peer-reviewed biology papers with all their internal findings? In other words, to what extent do clinical trial failures advance our understanding of biology?

I am asking in particular about Phase 2 and Phase 3 trials, because they seek to answer whether *Drug A* improves *Disease C*. Typically, *Drug A* attempts to affect *Drug Target B* which was believed to play a causal role in *Disease C*, so I wonder whether there tends to exist a process for revisiting the hypothesized biology of *Target B* (and revisiting the process that led to hypothesis) after *Drug A* fails.

Comment: You mean as opposed to burying the results or falsifying them? Sorry, just being honest and cynical (it happens a lot. Remember, the majority of pharmaceutical companies are in it for the big bucks. Money spent with no profitable potential outcome is not to be followed by more, unless there are potentially REALLY BIG BUCKS!!! ahead.) This site, btw, expects you to show evidence of *your* research into answering your question before we do so. Strange for a Q&A site, but this is an advanced Q&A site, if you will.

Comment: I clicked the wrong close box, but I think that questions about clinical trials are not about biology. They may or may not be acceptable on SE Medical Sciences, but getting a useful answer depends on having a list member with experience in the pharma/biotech industry — not very likely.

Comment: I don't know what you mean with a trial 'failing'? I run clinical trials and to me, at least, a 'failed' trial is one where something went wrong enough such that it caused erroneous data (e.g., inappropriate test design for the specific outcome measure), no data at all (e.g., fatal technical failure that could not be resolved) or other causes (e.g., COVID regulations that restrict patient access). I bet that's not what you're after.

Comment: @AliceD -- I have reworded the question to clarify that I meant that the drug program failed in the clinical trial. This is of course the fault of the drug program, not the trial itself.

Comment: @AliceD - I suspect that the OP is asking what happens if a newly developed substance is tested and fails to have the desired effect, but I'm not sure, as a drug program isn't a term I'm familiar with.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm asking!

Comment: What phase of trial?

Comment: @BryanKrause - Phase 2 and 3. I added clarification and explanation in the original question.